# Topos over an Accessible and Cocomplete category

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Some facts have been drawn to my attention that raise the following two conjectures to my mind:

1. Many good properties of domains, dcpos, are captured categorically by accessible, cocomplete categories.
2. Since every domain has a topos of sheaves, it stands that there should be a topos associated to every accessible, cocomplete category.  This topos is a categorification of the idea of the topos of sheaves over a domain.

Do these sound reasonable?

Comment: An accessible cocomplete category is generally called a (locally) presentable category. M.Bunge and A.Carboni have studied the left adjoint to the forget full functor from Grothendieck topos to presentable categories here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499400157X I havn't really thought about this,but maybe this is what you are after ? (it is at least a construction that attach a topos to any presentable category)

Comment: If you merely want to attach a topos to any presentable category, then you could just take the topos of presheaves over it. A better (i.e., more coherent with the intuition behind presentability) option is probably the subtopos of sheaves for the Grothendieck topology in which the covering sieves of an object $X$ are generated by suitably directed systems of suitably presented objects with colimit $X$. (Here "suitably" will presumably refer to the cardinal involved in the presentability of the given category.)